# Сокращение строчки кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как мне можно сократить данную строчку?

`maxn, maxm = a * maxm, a * maxm`

Например, почему нельзя написать так?

`maxn, maxm = a * maxm`

Comment: Слева кортеж, а справа что?

Comment: Я тут присваиваю переменным значения, что за кортежи?

Comment: tuple, базовый тип Питона. В справке, наверное, должен быть. Здесь он временный безымянный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что тогда слева две переменые, а справа - одна. Какое значение должно быть присвоено `maxm`?

Можно написать

```
maxn = maxm = a * maxm
```

Comment: Точно, как я сам не догадался, спасибо